# get number of hours between two date and two Time

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a DataGridView contains all the spots with (DateStarttasck, TimeStarttasck) and (DateEndtasck, TimeEndtask) made ​​in a given period (StartDate, EndDate), and I try to calculate the number of hours between (DateStarttasck, TimeStarttasck) and (DateEndtasck, TimeEndtask) during the period (StartDate, EndDate)
NB: DateStarttasck, TimeStarttasck are each separated in DateTimePicker
and same thing for (DateEndtasck, TimeEndtask) (StartDate, EndDate)
so I'm looking at first to do a combinaision between Time and date and then calculate the number of hours

```
 Dim sql As String = "select * from task where id_task = " & Textbox1.Text & " and  Datetasck  Between '" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "' And '" & DateTimePicker2.Text & "';"
    command.CommandText = sql

    connection.Open()
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim SQLAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(sql, connStr)
    SQLAdapter.Fill(ds, "connectString")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "connectString"
    DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns()
    connection.Close()
```

Comment: What are the types of DateStartTasck and TimeStartTasck? Why not use a DateTime object instead of seperate fields?

Comment: DateStartTasck its Date only and TimeStartTasck its Time Only, I separate them because in my database they are separate

Comment: Yes, but what data type are they?  Are they `DateTime` objects or strings, or what?  You mention them, but then they don't appear in your example code.

Comment: Hello, sql injection vulnerability. This code is practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: in my database , DateStartTasck are of type Date(sql) with this form (yyyy-MM-dd) , and TimeStartTasck are of type Time ( sql) with this form 00:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DateTime.TryParse` to attempt to convert the date string and time string into a single `DateTime` object, like this:

```
Dim dateValue As Date

If Date.TryParse(dateString + " " + timeString, dateValue) Then
    ' Successfully parsed date and time strings into the dateValue object
Else
    ' Unable to parse date and time strings
End If
```

Note: `dateString` is the date piece from the database and `timeString` is the time piece from the database.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add both date and time (start with start) and (end with end) 
**ex: IN C#**

```
    DateTime date_Start = DateTime.Parse(StartDate_txt.Text);
    DateTime Time_Start = DateTime.Parse(StartTime_txt.Text);
    date_Start.AddHours(double.Parse(Time_Start.Hour));

    DateTime date_End = DateTime.Parse(EndDate_txt.Text);
    DateTime Time_End = DateTime.Parse(EndTime_txt.Text);
    date_End.AddHours(double.Parse(Time_End.Hour));

    float Diff = date_End.Subtract(date_Start).Hours
```

i hope you got the idea sorry,it's in c# but hopefully you get the idea and it's same way in vb

Comment: yw,feel free to ask anything about it :D